# fancy verbatim - bold letters for the first 4 columns

Tags: listings, verbatim, bold

I am writing a book on Python and IPython. I want to insert in this book code listings of Python and IPython. 
For the code itself I have no problem customizing listings for my intents. 
Including code from IPython is a bit more tricky. I would like to make the `In [x]:` and `Out [x]:` of IPython in bold. For that I used so far the package `fancyvrb`, like that:

```
\begin{ipython}
\textbf{In [20]:} FirstQ*2
\textbf{Out[20]:} ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']

\textbf{In [21]:} SomeList=[0]*6

\textbf{In [22]:} SomeList
\textbf{Out[22]:} [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
\end{ipython}
```

However it's a bit annoying to type the `\textbf` everytime for all the `In`'s and `Out`'s.

Can some one point a way in which I can define that first X columns in a verbatim environment are made in bold ?

I also tried with listings that:

```
\lstset{classoffset=0,
        morekeywords={In, Out,27},keywordstyle=\textbf,
    classoffset=1        
}
\begin{lstlisting}
In [27]: x=2
\end{lstlisting}
```

but only the words In and Out are made in Bold not the number and the brackets ...

Maybe I am asking the wrong question also ?
Any insights on that will be welcomed ...

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around, bold the actual input and output and gray-out or normal text the In[n]/Out[n] ?

Comment: it's a matter of taste. When you use IPython on real, the "In" is Blue, the "Out" is red. I managed also to define that with morecomment=[n][\color{red}\textbf]{In\ [}{]\:}, this will be gray in the printed version. But I'd like to keep things simple - so I chose bold face for now. Maybe if I release my book as PDF I will make everything in color. But the book should be as convenient as possible to read on gray scale.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whoof, 
I found a solution myself - I share it with you guys, since I see many people are giving positive feedback to my question:

```
\lstset{
morecomment=[n][\textbf]{In\ [}{]\:},
morecomment=[n][\textbf]{Out\ [}{]\:},
}

\begin{lstlisting}
In [27]: x=2, x=[123]
Out [27]: 2
\end{lstlisting}
```

[image: Ipython Listings]

Comment: Well done!  And thanks for remembering to share your answer.

Comment: That's a nice solution, but there's a worry that what's actually going on is you're defining the in and out to be comments, (right?), which means that they aren't "semantically" treated like code. I don't think this is a problem, but the purist would surely want a solution that still treats the text as code, rather than comment...

Comment: @Seamus, well so to speak, but what I care about is to differentiate the look of "In:" and "Out:" so one who reads my book, knows that in not code to type.